# Simplest way to print out comma seperated of an assoc array column in PHP (from MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, associative

I have a mysql fetch that is populating an associative array with columns from the DB.
One of the columns names is AMOUNT.
so it looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 259 [YEARMONTH] => 201105 [AMOUNT] => 54 [VALUE] => 12 ) [1] => Array ( [ID] => 259 [YEARMONTH] => 201106 [AMOUNT] => 32 [VALUE] => 34 ) )
```

All I want to do is echo the AMOUNTs like this:

```
54,32
```

So that I don't have trailing or heading commas.

Any suggestion for an elegant solution for this ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Preconditions

- `$array` contains the array for all rows.

### Code

```
foreach ($array as $row) {

    $newArray[] = $row['AMOUNT']; //Add it to the new array

}
echo implode(',',$newArray); //Implode the array and echo it out.
```

If you are using PHP 5.3+, this following also works:

```
echo implode(",",array_map(function($a) { return $a["AMOUNT"]; }, $array));
```

Courtesy of Mearlyn

### More

- **[`implode`](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)** - Takes an array and a delimiter and returns a string of 'delimiter' separated values of the array.

Comment: This can be simplified a lot if he's using 5.3+: `echo implode(",",array_map(function($a) { return $a["AMOUNT"]; }, $array));`

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer if you have helpful insights like that. Added, thanks

Answer (score 1):

First make an array of all amounts and then [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the result.

Answer (score 1):

Do it WITH trailing or heading comma and then use http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php (or http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php respectively)

### Code

```
$a = '';
foreach ($test as $t)
    $a .= $t['AMOUNT'] . ',';
$result = rtrim($a, ',');
```

### Alternatives

Approaches with implode are correct too, but my solution is faster.

### Performance

Tested on 2 member array with 10000000 runs.

Solution suggested by Truth requires 171 second to run, solution suggested by Mearlyn required 358!! seconds to run and my solution requires only 18 seconds!!

I used pastebin.com/fKbxfpy1 to get mentioned times...

Comment: No need. There are native, built-in functions to do what he wants.

Comment: I agree, and they are faster on one dimensional array. But there it will mean two passes through array as described in PS

Comment: If you are going for performance, you really should use my approach (the one using rtrim). Solution suggested by Truth requires 171 second to run, solution suggested by Mearlyn required 358!! seconds to run and my solution requires only 18 seconds!!

I used http://pastebin.com/fKbxfpy1 to get mentioned times...